# How to programmatically save the content written in TextView to a text file when terminating the app?

Tags: swift, macos

I want to save the content of the text view when the user closes the app.
I used the following codes to do so, but I cannot get the up-to-date string of the textview when closing the app. So, the produced text file is blank.

How should I access to the `NSTextView` from `AppDelegate` to save its content?

##### ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {

static var textViewString: String = ""
@IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!{
    didSet{
        ViewController.textViewString = textView.string
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // start with hidden and show after moving to the main screen
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //keep the window top
        self.view.window?.level = .floating
        
        
        //set up the main display as the display where window shows up
        let screens = NSScreen.screens
        var pos = NSPoint()
        pos.x = screens[0].visibleFrame.midX
        pos.y = screens[0].visibleFrame.midY
        self.view.window?.setFrameOrigin(pos)
        
        
        self.view.window?.zoom(self)
        self.view.window?.level = .floating
        //self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        
        
        //stop the user from moving window
        self.view.window?.isMovable = false
        //disable resizable mode
        self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
        self.view.window?.setIsVisible(true)
    }
    //set up font for the reflectionForm
    textView.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    
    
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func saveTextViewString(){
    if let documentDirectoryFileURL = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).last {
        
        let fileName = "savedText.txt"
        let targetTextFilePath = documentDirectoryFileURL + "/" + fileName
        
        do {
            try ViewController.textViewString.write(toFile: targetTextFilePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("successfully recorded: \(ViewController.textViewString.description) at \(fileName.utf8CString)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("failed to write: \(error)")
            
        }
    }
}
}
```

#### AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
        
        
        //save the string in the textview into a text file
        ViewController().saveTextViewString()
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: You are creating a new view controller by calling ViewController(). You need a reference to your existing instance

Comment: Also, it’s very strange to use static for that string. It can just be an instance variable.

Comment: Thank you, @jnpdx. I did not know that`ViewController()` creates a new controller. I was using `static` to try accessing the previous ViewController's variable. It seems that I cannot simply do `ViewController.saveTextViewString()` to access to a method in `ViewController`. Could you show me what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the @jnpdx's comments, I was able to solve this by just declaring `ViewController` in the `AppDelegate` by stating `var viewController: ViewController!`

##### ViewController.swift

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
@IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // start with hidden and show after moving to the main screen
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //keep the window top
        self.view.window?.level = .floating
        
        
        //set up the main display as the display where window shows up
        let screens = NSScreen.screens
        var pos = NSPoint()
        pos.x = screens[0].visibleFrame.midX
        pos.y = screens[0].visibleFrame.midY
        self.view.window?.setFrameOrigin(pos)
        
        
        self.view.window?.zoom(self)
        self.view.window?.level = .floating
        //self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        
        
        //stop the user from moving window
        self.view.window?.isMovable = false
        //disable resizable mode
        self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
        self.view.window?.setIsVisible(true)
    }
    //set up font for the reflectionForm
    textView.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    
    
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func saveTextViewString(){
    if let documentDirectoryFileURL = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).last {
        
        let fileName = "savedText.txt"
        let targetTextFilePath = documentDirectoryFileURL + "/" + fileName
        
        do {
            try textView.string.write(toFile: targetTextFilePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("successfully recorded: \(textView.string.description) at \(fileName.utf8CString)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("failed to write: \(error)")
            
        }
    }
}
}
```

#### AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

//connect viewController with ViewController
var viewController: ViewController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
        
        
        //save the string in the textview into a text file
        viewController.saveTextViewString()
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```